# Rails: assets are missing in production(No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-12345.css")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, production, sprockets

I have Rails 4 application. When I'm running it in Development mode, everything works fine, but when I'm running it in Production mode, assets are missing with error from the topic.

Example how I'm using assets:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, media: 'all' %>
```

What's the problem? thanks for your time and help.

Error messages are like:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/application-562bac274264d04046337005941c14dc9909665bcdecf8739957ad529b009127.js 404 (Not Found)
```

My application.js and .css files (compiled versions) are in

```
myproject\public\assets
```

And application.js and .css files (source ones) are in

```
myproject\app\assets\javascrips and myproject\app\assets\stylesheets
```

I'm running app on Windows, if it's important.

Comment: Looking at your `404` error, you should run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` *before* you push to your production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in production, assets are [`precompiled`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) & [`fingerprinted`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark), hence calling them directly is not going to work. You have to call the **filename** *only*:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

You also need to make sure you keep your `stylesheets` / `javascripts` in the appropriate directories. Why you'd put `application.css` in `/javascripts` is beyond me.

---

The reason the above works is because they use the [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) helper, which allows Rails to pull the appropriate file from a set of *relative* paths. Rather like the [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) var in operating systems, it means you can call assets which may have been fingerprinted in production.

Comment: well, I tried this advice, and it doesn't work anyway. thanks. They're in proper directories, this directories paths are left when I've tried everything, sorry, forgot to delete them back

Comment: So I just wasted 10 minutes of my life writing it? No feedback? Nothing about your file structure? Come on dude, play the game.

Comment: Thanks for the update & extra context -- so you're getting a `404` error. That is okay; is this in production only, or does the issue happen in `development` too?

Comment: In development everything works fine, no 404's, assets are found. So it's production only issue

Comment: Okay thanks again. What prod environment are you running? Windows in prod?

Comment: Yes, Win 7, I'm running app on the same machine in development and production environments. It's not actual production server, I just wanted to check if it will run fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103592/discussion-between-richard-peck-and-andreys).

Comment: I've finally ran it on my VPS, and firstly it was running with 404's on assets again, but then I've set 'RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'] env variable and it fixed the problem, thanks again, Richard

Comment: No problem, if you have any more issues, please let me know & I will see if I can help resolve them